# A random walk in the plane

Tags: probability, random-walk

An urn contains two two coins with probabilities of heads $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively, such that $p_1+p_2>1$; that is, the coins are on average biased in favor of heads.  Two people each have initial wealth of $1$.  Each takes a coin from the urn, and each flips their coin.  Each gets $+1$ for a Head and $-1$ for a Tail.  They put their coins back in the urn, shake it up, and draw again.  They repeat this process until someone exhausts their wealth.  This describes a random walk in the plane that begins in $\mathbb Z^2_{++}$ and is absorbed at the boundary. The walk has a strictly positive drift. **Does this random walk terminate, that is, hit the boundary of $\mathbb Z^2_+$, with probability $1$?**  Any one person has a positive probability of surviving forever because her marginal process is a one-dimensional simple walk with positive drift.  But the two walks are dependent because if one person gets the good coin, the other gets the bad coin.  I want to know if, with positive probability, both survive forever.

Suppose I have $k$ coins like $p_1$ and $l$ coins like $p_2$ with $kp_1+lp_2>(k+l)/2$, and $k+l$ people, so the walk is now in $\mathbb{Z}^{k+l}_+$.  **Does this random walk hit the boundary of $\mathbb Z^{k+1}_+$ with probability $1$?**

Comment: I think this question needs to be clearer. What is $2d$ here? What is an orthant?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Agreed. This seems to be a one dimensional walk, and I've never heard of orthant before.

Comment: If $p_1=p_2>\frac12$, then both survive with positive probability. So the worst case scenario is "this depends on $p_1$ and $p_2$". I would need to think a little more about whether this is true answer, or whether you *always* have positive probability that both survive.

Comment: $p_1>1/2$ and $p_2<1/2$ but the average exceeds $1/2$ is the interesting case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The termination probability is always less than $1$. This follows from using the law of large numbers twice. First, for any $\varepsilon>0$ and for sufficiently large $n$, there is a positive probability that each player chooses the better coin at least $(\frac12-\varepsilon)t$ times out of the first $t$ for every $t>n$. We can choose $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small that $(\frac12-\varepsilon)p_1+(\frac12+\varepsilon)p_2>\frac12$. We also have positive probability that all the tosses before this $n$ will be heads.

Now for any sequence of coin choices with this property, there is a positive probability that for all $t>n$ each player has got a proportion at least $p_1-\delta$ heads on the times he has tossed coin $1$ up to time $t$, and a proportion of at least $p_2-\delta$ heads on the times he has tossed coin $2$. Choosing $\delta$ sufficiently small, this implies that neither player has gone bankrupt.

Comment: Thank you.  I think this nails it.